# Endless scrolling in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get some data(basically pictures) from a webpage which has endless scrolling. To get the data I need to click a button. The page is different for some cases and ends sometimes after 5 elements or sometimes after 250 elements. At the moment I tried the following:

```
lastElement = driver.findElement(By.id("picture_id"));
WebElement submit_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Submit']"));
submit_button.click();
```

However, the page does not get refreshed.

What is the right way to deal with endless scrolling in selenium? How to deal with large amounts of elements on a page, especially if it is some `heavy content` like pictures, which usually does not load very fast?

I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the way that I would do it, by creating my own method that is a scrollDown method:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
...
public void scrollDownPage( int pix ) {
    if ( pix <= 0 || pix > 1000 ) pix = 250;
    jse.executeScript("scroll(0, pix)");
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! What I do not get is, what is `pix` and why is it set to `250`?

Comment: The var pix is short for pixels .

Comment: Thx for your answer! When I would put in `scroll down for 10000 pixels` and the page cannot scroll down that much. Would that matter?

Comment: Furthermore, if after the `10000 pixels` there is still an element I want to get, how to get this?

Comment: if you need to scroll to a certain element, or to the nth element, then you can still do that with a javascriptexecutor.   the scrollDown method I gave above is meant to be called multiple times to get iteratively down the page.    it all depends on what behavior you want... you can do just about anything.   no, javascript will not error if you cant scroll down any further.